# Deserializing derived Types

Tags: c#, xml

I've got a Class Hierarchy which is inherited from a Base Class. I want to deserialize all that Types from XML. Documentation says to use this Constructor for that purposes:

```
XmlSerializer(Type type, Type[] extraTypes);
```

So I do something like this:

```
public class SomeBase { public string SomeProperty { get; set } }
public class SomeChild : SomeBase { public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; } }
```

Then I create XmlSerializer and try to deserialize my XML:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeBase),
   new Type[] { typeof(SomeChild) });
SomeBase deserialized = (SomeBase)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(myXml));
```

And I get InvalidOperationException which says:

```
"<SomeChild xmlns=''> was not expected."
```

How can I solve this?

**Update**
Here is my XML:

```
// Works fine:
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>
<SomeBase>
   <SomeProperty>some value</SomeProperty>
</SomeBase>
// InvalidOperationException:
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>
<SomeChild>
   <SomeProperty>some value</SomeProperty>
   <SomeOtherProperty>some other value</SomeOtherProperty>
</SomeChild>
```

Comment: What does your xml file look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the serializer that SomeBase can also be a SomeChild.
You can do that with the XmlInclude attribute

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SomeChild))]
public class SomeBase { public string SomeProperty { get; set } }
public class SomeChild : SomeBase { public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; } }
```

Comment: there is still the same exception